# your connection is not private in my application

Tags: java, security, servlets

Here is my site https://sample.in I placed the another webapplicaton in the same domain,its home page url is

http://www.sample.in:8080/anotherapplication-name/login.jsp

the above url is login page,when enter the credentials its navigating to main site url like

https://sample.in/anotherapplication-name/NavigationFrameset.jsp

In the browser i am getting the following message

**Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from www.ilovesalesevents.in (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID**

Please any help!!!!!!!

Comment: Did you self-sign the certificate? If you want to use HTTPS so that browsers see a secure connection you have to request a certificate from one of the [Certificate Authorities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority). Self-signed certificates will not be trusted.

Comment: "You can also click Advanced on the left-hand side of the warning to learn more about it." - did you do that?

Comment: here the problem is after login its navigating to http://www.sample.in:8080/anotherapplication-name/NavigationFrameset.jsp

Comment: Try http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f120/your-connection-is-not-private-issue-950178.html

Comment: @BackSlash for selfsigned Firefox would say "The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed" and "Error code: sec_error_ca_cert_invalid)" which are obviously not this question; plus just by connecting to the website stated you can see that the cert is issued by Comodo/PositiveSSL.

Answer (score 0):

**Your cert does not match your domain name.**

You're not clear which application is "another", but the domain names `[www.]sample.in` resolve to 192.254.254.73 
which is using a cert that was issued to `[www.]vb.in` -- and also expired 3 months ago (Feb 18). `[www.]vb.in` doesn't exist according to all authoritative DNS servers except one I couldn't reach,
and my ISPs have (presumably stale) records mapping these names to 92.242.140.21 and 198.105.244.11 which both don't respond at all.

For most uses of SSL/TLS including HTTPS, **the server cert must contain the domain name(s)** "of" the server, or more exactly the domain name(s) used to reach the server. If you want to use domain name(s) `[www.]sample.in`, you must get a certificate for that domain name(s).